# Как передать String в POST Spring

Tags: spring, post, rest

Можно ли как то передать только строку без привязки к какому то объекту в post запросе? и как в таком случае должен выглядеть json?

Допустим я хочу передать строку объекту с индексом в моем случае.

Я сделал так

```
@PostMapping("/model/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Model> change(
        @RequestParam String value,
        @PathVariable Long id
) {
    //.. логика
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Model);
}
```

как эту строку передать на вход через json?

```
{
    "value":"value"
}
```

и так

```
[
    "value"
]
```

не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы принимать запрос строкой Вам нужно использовать аннотацию `@RequestBody` вместо `@RequestParam`.

Как будет выглядеть Ваш код:

```
@PostMapping("/model/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Model> change(
        @RequestBody String json,
        @PathVariable Long id
) {
    //.. логика
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Model);
}
```

В таком случае, вы можете использовать любой формат json`a и не только его, Spring все вернет как строку.

Почитать [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body).